# How to parameterize mysql like query?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, parameters, sql-like

This is my code but it gives me a fatal error encountered during execution

```
private void recregtxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (recregcmb.Text == "Student ID")
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select StudID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleInitial, Address, Age, Birthday, Gender, Guardian, ContactNumber as 'Contact Number', Year as 'Year Level' from registeredTBL where StudID LIKE @key", conn);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = data;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", recregtxt.Text + "%");
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this please.

Answer (score 3):

Because you try to add your parameter name and it's value *after* you execute it with your data adapter. You should add if *before* you execute it.

```
if (recregcmb.Text == "Student ID")
{
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select StudID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleInitial, Address, Age, Birthday, Gender, Guardian, ContactNumber as 'Contact Number', Year as 'Year Level' from registeredTBL where StudID LIKE @key", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", recregtxt.Text + "%");
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(data);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = data;
}
```

A few things more;

- Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your data adapter automatically.

By the way, there is *no* `cmd` in your method. Define your command and connection in your method with disposing them `using` statement as well.

Comment: `A few things more;` makes your answer perfect...!

Comment: Now I get a NullReferenceException error in line of parameter. Why is it happening?

Comment: @AdrianRamos You still use `AddWithValue` or you changed it to `Add`? Can you please show the relevant line? Debug your code and see what is `null`. You can check: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156) as well.

Comment: Both Add and AddWithValue give me the same error at this line cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", recregtxt.Text + "%");

Comment: @AdrianRamos Because there is no `cmd` in your method and it probably comes as `null` if you define it out of your scope. Define both connection and command in your method instead and you will be fine.

Comment: I moved the connection and command code from outside to inside my method but now it gives me 'use of unassigned local variable' error.

Comment: @AdrianRamos Initialize your connection and command like `var conn = new MySqlConnection(yourConString)` and `var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()`.

Answer (score 1):

**What is wrong with your code:**

You are almost there but You are executing the query without adding the parameter value, and adding the parameter value after the execution of the command:

**What you have to do:**

Add parameter value before executing the query, So you snippet will be like the following:

```
   if (recregcmb.Text == "Student ID")
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select StudID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleInitial, Address, Age, Birthday, Gender, Guardian, ContactNumber as 'Contact Number', Year as 'Year Level' from registeredTBL where StudID LIKE @key", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@key", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = recregtxt.Text + "%";
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = data;                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            conn.Open();
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select StudID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleInitial, Address, Age, Birthday, Gender, Guardian, ContactNumber as 'Contact Number', Year as 'Year Level' from registeredTBL where StudID LIKE @key;";
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", recregtxt.Text + "%");
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = data;
```

I don't know why but this code worked, when I use Add instead of AddWithValue, the compiler gives me error about invalid datetime something but thank you all for helping.